# Is there any way to mask or encrypt a number in chat app in Android?

Tags: android, chat

I created a chat app inside my application.  In the chat application (SMSActivity) I have the code

```
editText.setText(phoneNo);
```

Is there any way to mask that number so the user sending the message doesn't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `android:inputType="textPassword"` on the EditText.

Comment: Learn something new every day :)

Comment: It works for texting, but not for calling, is there a way to mask the number on the dialer?

Comment: No. You don't have control over what the dialer looks like.

Comment: much appreciated